# Assistance with awk command

Tags: awk

Hello I have a log file where "each" of the log line is in below format:

```
Jun 26 11:10:27 ip-1-4-5-6 snx: {"@message":"Successful response body: {\"payload\":
[{
\"LID\":\"\",
\"EID\":\"75~1\",
\"SNFlag\":1,
\"Error\":\"Match found\"

},{\"LID\":\"\",
\"EID\":\"78~10\",
\"SNFlag\":1,
\"Error\":\"Match found\"

},{\"LID\":\"\",
\"EID\":\"385~25\",
\"SNFlag\":1,
\"Error\":\"Match found\"

},{\"LID\":\"3e76j5866\",
\"EID\":\"85~26\",
\"SNFlag\":1},

},{\"LID\":\"\",
\"EID\":\"33~9\",
\"SNFlag\":1,
\"Error\":\"Match found\"

}]} UniqueNonce: 1593169824239","@timestamp":"2020-06-26T11:10:27.837Z","@fields":{"gID":"sand_entry","logID":"x82","component":"ABC","level":"info"}}
```

Can I please get some help with the below as I have tried several trial and error method but failed to get exact count. My requirement is, whenever there is an error that says "Match found" i need to print the EID of such lines and then the count of it in the entire log file. Please note that the format specified above is only of one log line and I have many such lines in my log file.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Good that you have mentioned that you have tried many things to solve your problem. Its all recommended on SO to add those efforts into your question too so kindly do so(there is nothing wrong or right here as we all are here to learn) cheers.

Comment: Whenever you have multiple records in your real data you should include at least 2 records in the sample input in your question. Also make sure to include the expected output in your question. Otherwise we're doing a lot of guessing (e.g. I can imagine several things that `it` might be in the statement `...the count of it...` - the count of errors? the count of unique EIDs that have an error? the count of errors per EID? etc.)

Comment: Are you **sure** that's exactly the format of a log file record? Your terminating `}` doesn't match up with any opening `{`. The `{` at the start of `{"@message"` matches up with the `}` at the start of `} UniqueNonce` and the `{` at the start of `{"gID"` matches the first `}` in `"info"}}` leaving the second/final `}` hanging on it's own with no starting `{`.

Comment: Could you please do lemme know if my answer helped you?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples with GNU `awk`.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk -F"\"" '
/\\"Error\\":\\"Match found\\"/{
  found=1
}
found && /EID/{
  sub(/\\/,"",$(NF-1))
  print $(NF-1)
  count++
  found=""
}
END{
  print "Total matches found are:" count
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
tac Input_file |                                 ##Printing Input_file in reverse order to get line with ERROR before EID line to make it easy.
awk -F"\"" '                                     ##Sending tac output to awk and setting field separator as " here.
/\\"Error\\":\\"Match found\\"/{                 ##Checking condition if line has \"Error\":\"Match found\" in it then do following.
  found=1                                        ##Setting found here which is proof that Error line has found in current line.
}
found && /EID/{                                  ##Checking condition if found is SET and current line has EID in it then do following.
  sub(/\\/,"",$(NF-1))                           ##Substituting \ with NULL in 2nd last field.
  print $(NF-1)                                  ##Printing 2nd last field here which has actual EID value in it.
  count++                                        ##Increasing count value by 1 here.
  found=""                                       ##Nullifying found here.
}
END{                                             ##Starting END block from here.
  print "Total matches found are:" count         ##Printing total count of matches here for whole Input_file.
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F \" '/EID/{ sub(/\\/,"",$(NF-1)); eid=$(NF-1); print eid }' Input_file
```

Will print all the `eid` values like this:

```
75~1
78~10
385~25
85~26
33~9
```

Because you only want to print the `eid` when there is in `error`, change this (and add a `count`):

```
awk -F \" '/EID/{ sub(/\\/,"",$(NF-1)); eid=$(NF-1); }
          /Error/{ print eid; count++;}
          END{ print "Count:" count } ' Input_file
```

output:

```
75~1
78~10
385~25
33~9
Count:4
```